# Action_dt fields purpose in PS_POSITION_DATA in peoplesoft

Tags: peoplesoft

What is the purpose Action_dt in PS_position_data table?
What exactly is this field say here?

Answer (score 2):

This field indicates the date that the action was performed (like add a new row), it is not the effdt, which can be different from the action dt.